# (C#) Getting a files properties and putting them in a message box

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

So I've used this site for some VBA stuff I did in the past and found some great help by other users' questions. Now I've begun using C# and am totally lost on how to get the details from a file. I will admit, I am completely new to C# and am having a pretty difficult time getting used to it.
What I'm trying to do is choose a directory (already have that in place with FolderBrowserDialog), and then grab all the names of the folders in that directory, and all of the subfolders. 
To put it in to context, I want to go to my Music folder, and then be able to make a list of all the artists and albums in that directory in a textbox. Each album will be under the Artist folder, so the whole thing would read the name of one folder, then all the subfolders in that folder, then go back and move on to the next one.

Not sure if anyone will ask, but here is all the code I have:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DirButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK);
        {
            DirBox.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and I'll try to understand your answer(s) as best as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not C++. I'm guessing C#.

Comment: As for your problem, if by "properties" you mean e.g. song and album title etc., then  you probably should try and go through the C# documentation and references on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) to see if there's a class which can load the file-type you want to get information about, and then extract the specific meta-data for that kind of file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I've been browsing too many things and forgot what I was writing in lol.
I did find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfileinfo(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). I believe that is what I need to use, but I'm not sure how to put it in to practice in the way that I'm wanting to use it.

Comment: Hey, @TommyPatton, please check out my answer below. It will get you through the first steps. Although you will need to change the structure of your code to first get artist folders, and then as a next step get albums for each of the artist. If you do a recursive search, you will have a problem - how to group all the data in a flat array you have for each artist / album

Answer (score 0):

One of the many options would be to use `Directory.GetDirectories`, see [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your code could look something like this:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(fbd.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Depending on the structure of your folders, you might need to use another `SearchOption Enumeration` - use 'AllDirectories' to do a recursive search, or `TopDirectoryOnly` to look only in the top directory, see [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now, if you don't need a recursive search you can use a simpler overload `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx), sample follows:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(fbd.SelectedPath);
```

Please note that you can do the same by using `DirectoryInfo` class instead of `Directory` class if you prefer to have an instance rather than working with statics, be sure to check out the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks so much for the advice! I'll have to research this then  try it all out later on, but if I run in to any more trouble I'll likely head back here.

Comment: Hi @TommyPatton, did you have a chance to try this out? Do you need any help?

Comment: Hey @ironstone13 Thanks for the help, and sorry for the super late response. I had some events happen in my life that sort of put everything on hold for a month, but I'm back to learning to code these things. So, I've got that in place, I didn't get any errors, so everything looks good. Now I just need to get a button to put that information in an output box, and I'll basically be done. But, I'm not going to ask for help with that. Time for me to do something on my own for once lol

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out. I got it to do what I want and I'm at the point that I'm trying to keep from having the directory in the output. It seems like string [] isn't going to do what I want it to, unless there is a sort of Regex.Replace type method that I'm not able to find. 

Example of what it currently looks like:
F:\Music\Music\Artist\Album

What I'm trying to make it look like:
Artist-Album

Any suggestions?